# Anbox: Failed to connect to dbus ubuntu 21.04

Tags: dbus, adb, anbox

I just installed [anbox](https://anbox.io/) on ubuntu 21.04 using snap:

```
snap install --devmode --beta anbox
```

However if I try to run anbox, for example:

```
 /snap/bin/anbox launch --package=org.anbox.appmgr --component=org.anbox.appmgr.AppViewActivity
```

I get a error `[daemon.cpp:61@Run] Failed to connect to DBus`

What did I make wrong? How can I debug this and make it work?

`adb` also doesn't list any emulators:

```
adb devices                             
List of devices attached
```

Comment: Please file a bug report with the Snap author. That looks to me like something that the snap author needs to fix.

Comment: It also looks like it is a BETA version?